# Initialize larger-than-memory Xarray Dataset

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, zarr

I would like to initialize a very large XArray dataset (as on-disk Zarr if possible) for later processing - various parts (spatial subsets) of the dataset will be populated by a different script.

This won't work, because the dataset obviously doesn't fit into memory.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
xr_lons = xr.DataArray(np.arange(-180, 180, 0.001), dims=['x'], name='lons')
xr_lats = xr.DataArray(np.arange(90, -90, -0.001), dims=['y'], name='lats')
xr_da = xr.DataArray(0, dims=['y', 'x'], coords=[xr_lats, xr_lons])
xr_ds = xr.Dataset({"test": xr_da})
xr_ds.to_zarr("test.zarr", mode="w")
```

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 483. GiB for an array with shape (180000, 360000) and data type int64`

What would be a good alternative?

I'm looking for a solution like this using plain zarr:

```
import zarr
root = zarr.open('example.zarr', mode='w')
mosaics = root.create_group('mosaics')
dsm = mosaics.create_dataset('dsm', shape=(nrows, ncols), chunks=(1024, 1024), dtype='i4')
```

The dataset, however, doesn't conform to the normal XArray structure and metadata so I'm looking for a solution directly using XArray (or Dask?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dask` to "initialize" an `xarray` Dataset which is backed by a lazy `dask` array and then write it to disk in chunks concurrently.

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

lat = np.arange(90, -90, -0.001)
lon = np.arange(-180, 180, 0.001)

x = xr.Dataset(
    coords={
        "lat": (["lat"], lat),
        "lon": (["lon"], lon),
    },
    data_vars={
        "dsm": (
            ["lat", "lon"],
            da.zeros((lat.size, lon.size), chunks=(1024, 1024), dtype="uint8"),
        )
    },
)
```

This gives you an `xarray` dataset with a dask array `dsm`:

[image]

You can now do any kind of further modification or just write it to disk using `.to_zarr`.

A couple of notes:

Your array is fairly large, choosing the correct datatype is crucial. If not specified it'll use `float64` which will be `483. GiB` for your array. If you specify for instance `uint8` like in my example, it'll be only `60.35 GiB` for the same size.

Another crucial factor is the chunk size. Using `(1024, 1024)` from your example yields very small chunks which means a ton of tasks which will likely result in issues for either dask or your disk I/O.